# Match string to an ActiveRecord Object with a substring attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have an ActiveRecord Model with a column 'title'. The title might be "coding challenge". The function is presented with a string such as "this new coding challenge is really difficult".

I am looking for a way to query the db and match the string to the model. I've thought of using LIKE SQL, but the given string is always larger than the substring in the model.

So what I am looking for is something like - given_string.include? Model.titles that returns the record or nil if no match

Comment: @engineersmnky `Regexp.union(Model.distinct.pluck(:title))`  I am not sure `Regexp` length capacities are infinite.

Comment: @engineersmnky I understand it is a solution (unless `Regexp#union` gets confused by the number of distinct titles.)

Comment: Why not `M.where("? like '%' || column || '%'", given_string)`? Won't be the quickest but it might be fast enough and if not, at least a starting point.

Comment: @muistooshort brilliant, thank you - that is perfect! Speed shouldn't be an issue, this model is fixed to 100 or so records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL's LIKE operator has strings on both sides so you can turn it around and say "is this string literal like this pattern built from a column":

```
M.where(":string like '%' || column || '%'", string: given_string)
```

Again, this won't be super fast but it should be fast enough for small tables.